# Am I supposed to have an app insights resource per system application or per environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a system made up of 2 `WebApi` apps, 1 `MVC`/`WebApi` app that serves as `STS`, and the main `MVC` site just loads `angular`. These are to be hosted in `azure`. Am I supposed to have 1 `AppInsights` resource for each one of those components in each of my environments (4 apps * 3 env = 12 AppInsights resources) or am I supposed to just have one per environment and share the key across all the different apps in one environment so that all of my telemetry ends up in a single "bucket"?

If anyone with telemetry/analytics experience can provide some input, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:11/2021** given it is ~5 years since i answered this last time, a lot of things have changed. Many of the things are different now.

In 2020/2021, there was work to combine Log Analytics and Application Insights, so now you can have N application insights resources that all point to a *single* workspace.  This makes merging/querying across many resources a LOT simpler, simplifies a lot of other things like billing since you're billed for the one workspace instead of the N app insights resources, etc.  There are are also a lot of features of Log Analytics that become supported when you use the log analytics backed setup.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource

There's now an azure docs page now that discusses this topic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/separate-resources
(from the doc)

> #### When to use a single Application Insights resource
>
> For application components that are deployed together. Usually developed by a single team, managed by the same set of DevOps/ITOps users.
>
> - If it makes sense to aggregate Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) such as response durations, failure rates in dashboard etc., across all of them by default (you can choose to segment by role name in the Metrics Explorer experience).
> - If there is no need to manage Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) differently between the application components.
> - If you don't need metrics alert criteria that are different between the components.
> - If you do not need to manage continuous exports differently between the components.
> - If you do not need to manage billing/quotas differently between the components.
> - If it is okay to have an API key have the same access to data from all components. And 10 API keys are sufficient for the needs across all of them.
> - If it is okay to have the same smart detection and work item integration settings across all roles.

2016 answer (with strikethroughs):
up to you, and rather subjective. things to consider:

- it really depends on what data you want to be able to analyze *together*.  If you want to be able to track the same user/request through all the layers, you might use one resource for all the layers, and pass something like a correlation-id through all the requests/etc to be able to see something ripple through all the layers.  doing analysis across/between resources is complicated, and generally requires using something like Continuous Export and other tools outside the portal
- however, if different teams own the different layers, they might want to do their telemetry differently, so they might each want their own "application".
- <s>There's a limit on the number of distinct named custom properties and metrics each application is allowed to have (200 of each as of right now?), so if you mash them all together, you might use up the custom properties quickly.</s>  (the customDimensions field is now json, so this is effectively not true in 2021)
- There's also throttling limits on every individual application, and a limit of the number of webtests each application can have.  So if you use just one app for all the environments/layers, and one of your layers goes crazy, it might throttle all of your data and you might lose telemetry until the crazyiness goes away and throttling is lifted for that component.
- If "environment" in your case is dev/test/staging/prod, you probably **do** want those to be separate, so data from developers doing random crashy things doesn't pollute your production telemetry.
- if environment is really "instance" then you probably **don't** want separate applications for that, but telemetry from each instance should ideally be identifying itself so you can filter/group by to see if one specific instance is doing something out of the ordinary